# C# WebBrowser Control intercept Download in New Window from PHP script

Tags: c#, download, browser, controls

I am attempting to automate interaction with a website that retruns data in CSV when a button is clicked.
I am using the WebBrowser control with C#.net
I am able to click the button on the web page using HtmlElement object.
My HtmlElement object is called HtmlEl.
I invoke clicking the button with:
HtmlEl.InvokeMember("click");
This then results in a new IE window opening and then displays the download dialog.
I have been trying to find a way to control this download so it can be automated, but not having much luck.
I have found methods where if I had a URL link to the download it can be done, but this does not have any link. I am being delivered a CSV result from a seperate PHP page being invoked by the button I press.
Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the NewWindow event in the webbrowser control. This will give you access to the DOM of the window with the download dialog.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.newwindow(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You only get the DOM of the original browser and the opportunity to cancel the new window entirely.